# What action is changing your grip on a weapon with the two-hand poperty?

Tags: weapons, actions, pathfinder-2e

The Fighter feat Dual-handed Assault (CRB p146) lets you grip your weapon with 2 hands, strike, and release it with one of your hands, all in one action.

How many actions would it be without the feat?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## It's an Interact action

According to [Archives of Nethys: Dual-Handed Assault](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=371).

> You snap your free hand over to grip your weapon just long enough to add momentum and deliver a more powerful blow to your opponent.
> Make a Strike with the required weapon. You quickly switch your grip during the Strike in order to make the attack with two hands. If the weapon doesn’t normally have the two-hand trait, increase its weapon damage die by one step for this attack. (Rules on increasing die size appear on page 279.)
> If the weapon has the two-hand trait, you gain the benefit of that trait and a circumstance bonus to damage equal to the weapon’s number of damage dice. When the Strike is complete, you resume gripping the weapon with only one hand.
> This action doesn’t end any stance or fighter feat effect that requires you to have one hand free.

Changing your grip on a weapon with the two-handed trait (not to be confused with actual two-handed weapons) like a bastards sword requires an interact action, as noted at [Archive of Nethys: Wielding Items](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=194).

Comparing this to the same activity without the feat:

- Change grip = 1 Interact action - Potentially interrupting stances and effects
- Striking = 1 Strike action
- Dropping grip = 1 free action - drop item of one hand (No consequence)

Total: **2 actions**

With the feat:

- Change grip = Part of the feat action - Without consequences
- Strike = Part of the same action - Increased dmg
- Drop grip = Part of the same action

Total: **1 actions**

## Examples on advantages

- Increased damage for for 1 action and without any consequences.
- Any one-handed weapons can be treated as having a two-handed trait, allowing you to increase it's damage die.
- Maintain a free hand at your disposal
- As the feat is not a manipulate action, it this would not provoke an AOE.

Comment: You can draw a weapon with two hands on it as part of one interact, you don't have to change your grip if you started with it in two hands.

Comment: @Delioth I can't find any explicit rules on how many hands are used as part of a draw interact action, so removed the sheathed section for now. In order to rest this case entirely - Have you got any source on weapons can be drawn with both hands?

Comment: @KasperThystrupKarstensen Well, it's pretty intuitive. Unless you're going to require that someone drawing their greatsword needs two actions to draw the weapon and put a hand on it. Since the rules around drawing a weapon are pretty fluid and just covered by the Interact action (there is no specific "Draw" action or sub-action), it's meant to be an intuitive thing, and nothing says you must only use one hand - interacting with both hands at once makes more sense than interacting with one hand, and then with the other.

Comment: @Delioth Sure that makes sense, I guess I accidently pictured it as drawing with one hand (e.g. maul on your back) and shifting your other hand to grip the handle to be two seperate actions (in correspondence to the required interact action, if you let go of the handle while allready drawn)

Comment: you might want to link to the [relevant part of the rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=194)